# Overlap image with another image

Tags: html, css, background, flexbox

1. First image is going as a background with its multiply blend mode and its color (100% x 1172px).
2. At the very bottom of this container is a block (50% x 520px) with same background, but without blending mode.
3. [What exactly I'm trying to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsf8c.jpg).

-- The idea is to keep these two image as a single one at least to >= 920px width of breakpoint.

HTML&CSS markup

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 1172px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main__fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.main__fluid--image {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/eRnGawp.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.main__inner-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  height: 520px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  z-index: 9;
}

.main__inner-block--image-mask {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Piu55zF.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top -36rem center;
  max-width: 100%:
}

.main__navigation {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5ec8c3;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #1f5c71;
  height: 91px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="main__fluid main__fluid--image">
    <div class="main__inner-block main__inner-block--image-mask">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently have this one:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndawqkpy/6/)
[jsfiddle (UPD)](https://jsfiddle.net/ndawqkpy/8/)

**UPD: found somewhat partial solution**

I will assign **parent** for big image *(which is with blending mode)*
and **child** for smaller image *(which is without blending mode)*

Actually I just deleted property `background-size` from **parent** or/and add `background-size: auto auto` to its style, the idea is to, of course, prevent resizing on Y axis. Then did tweaks for **child** to fit it relative **parent** through `background-position` and the last one, aligned them centered with `background-position: center`. Updated jsfiddle with these changes.

Comment: Can you migrate your code from codeply to your question here?

Comment: @Vandal Sure, one minute.

Comment: background-position and max-width may help 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/

Answer (score 1):

Try this css block. It will align both images into same position.

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 1172px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main__fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.main__fluid--image {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Piu55zF.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #51c8c4;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top -27rem center;


}

.main__inner-block {
  position: relative;
  height: 45%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 20.5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28)
}

.main__inner-block--image-mask {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Piu55zF.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top -45rem center;
}
```